How can I use msgraph Python SDK to properly list or get files from OneDrive?
I have a corporate account and I asked to set up Application Permission with the scope Files.ReadWrite.All to be able to access msgraph Python SDK in order to use Drive/DriveItem APIs under the "Files" documentation of msgraph.
I am not able to understand how to use the SDK though. After creating a client with my credential, I tried different requests without success, meaning that I am not able to see what I expect.
So I wish to ask, if I have the following URL:
https://mycompany-my.sharepoint.com/my?id=%2Fpersonal%2my_user_id%2FDocuments%2FDocuments

Which is a folder named "Documents" under "My Files" in my Onedrive for Business dashboard (which seems like a sharepoint library). How can I query it?
I tried, for instance, examples like this:
self.client.users.by_user_id(user_id).drives.by_drive_id(drive_id).items
self.client.users.by_user_id(user_id).drives.by_drive_id(drive_id).root.children.get()

My problem, is that after I get my desired Drive object (I believe), I am not able to access the items/root attributes because either they don't exist (so I am making a bad requests) or they exist but are None values.
I am able to list 2 drives, one named "OneDrive" which is the one I use as ID, and the other one is a PersonalCache.

"Which is a folder named "Documents" under "My Files" in my Onedrive for Business dashboard (which seems like a sharepoint library). How can I query it" Can you attach a screenshot of what you want to query?

@Rukmini the exact endpoint URL is provided in the example, with placeholder named where personal information are expected, like user_id and my corporate path. Anyway I can upload a screenshot if it is really needed. Can you explain what you wish to see? I wish to be able to "see" that folder, either by listing the items inside it, for get the folder metadata, or queries like those.

To access root item, you can call by_drive_item_id('root').
If you know drive id, you can omit users.by_user_id(user_id)
childItems = await self.client.drives.by_drive_id(drive_id)
               .items.by_drive_item_id('root').children.get()

It will return only 200 items from the first page.
Example how to implement paging can be found in SDK repo:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python?tab=readme-ov-file#32-pagination

I am not able to use .items after .by_drive_id(...) because the returned object (if I use .get()) has items attribute None

@Luca You should use get() only at the end after children

await drive_dao.client.users.by_user_id(drive_dao.user_id).drives.by_drive_id(drive_dao.drive_id).items.by_drive_item_id('root').children.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'DriveItemRequestBuilder' object has no attribute 'items'

@Luca It's clear what's wrong. Good point is that you can omit users.by_user_id(drive_dao.user_id) and use await drive_dao.client.drives.by_drive_id(drive_dao.drive_id).items.by_drive_item_id('root').children.get() because drive id is unique across all drives in the tenant.

Your suggestion works, do you mind elaborating more what was wrong by pre-appending the users.by_user_id calls?

The issue is with Microsoft Graph SDK which doesn't generate code for all endpoints to avoid being oversized and to avoid generation of redundant paths. That's the case of GET /users/{user_id}/drives/{drive_id}/items/root/children which has an alternate path GET /drives/{drive_id}/items/root/children

Thank you, on the other hand, how can I see the reference documentation to get to know the available endpoints and methods on those objects? For instance, I wish to understand what is available with DriveItemItemRequestBuilder. Where can I see it?
